# getting an error when starting up emacs related to global-linum-mode

Tags: emacs

Hi All: I am using ubuntu 22.10. Recently ( as in just today ), I started to get the error
at the very bottom when starting up emacs using emacs --debug-init. I have not recently
updated emacs or ubuntu.

As far as possibilities, I only have linum-mode in one place in my dot emacs file and it's right here.

### Code in `.emacs` file

```lisp
(setq inhibit-startup-message t)  ;; Hide the startup message
(load-theme 'material t)          ;; Load material theme
(global-linum-mode t)             ;; Enable line numbers globally
```

I could just take the line out and see if that avoids the error but , with that approach,
I won't learn anything and I need to get better with understanding my dot emacs file and how
things work underneath the emavc start up hood. Thanks for any insights. Oh, I've googled
and will continue googling but so far no luck.

### Error when starting up Emacs

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function global-linum-mode)
  (global-linum-mode t)
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/markleeds/.emacs" "/home/markleeds/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" noerror nomessage)
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x14a857e1dea6ad3f>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c61addc0b8a75>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

I didn't try anything. Originally,  I did emacs myfile.txt and got a shorter error. Then it told
me to use the `--debug-init` option to get a traceback so that's what I did.
I will google more because I figure that someone must have had a similar problem
and solved it. I am using emacs 29.1. Thanks.

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/78369/what-to-use-instead-of-linum-mode-in-emacs-29/78370#78370

Comment: If you've encountered this issue while trying to set up Emacs using the configuration files from the book 'Clojure for the Brave and True,' you can resolve it by searching for the line 'global-linum-mode' in the 'ui.el' file and replacing it with 'global-display-line-numbers-mode 1'.

Answer (score 7):

I googled more carefully and was more determined this time, and the answer was to change that line in the file `/home/markleeds/.emacs`
that contained the entry

```
(global-linum-mode t) ;; Enable line numbers globally
```

For the following:

```
(global-display-line-numbers-mode 1) ;; Enable line numbers globally
```

It seems that the original line that stopped working  was used for older versions of Emacs, but this newer command is for later versions. Thanks
to all who read my question and my apologies for noise.